# Detect changes in HorizontalAlignment or VerticalAlignment

Tags: .net, wpf

I like to use the control described in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/54472/Defining-WPF-Adorners-in-XAML) to work with adorners. My example code looks like this:

```
<local:AdornedControl IsAdornerVisible="True"
                      Margin="60">
    <local:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>
        <Ellipse Width="50" Height="50"
                 Stroke="Green"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </local:AdornedControl.AdornerContent>

    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Test 1" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Test 2" />
            <ListBoxItem Content="Test 3" />
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</local:AdornedControl>
```

Basically it's a control in which you can describe the adorner's visual in XAML. And with this you can actually see the adorner's content in the XAML design window.

With the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the control in `AdornerContent` you can say, whether the adorner is attached to the left side or the right side of the adorned control. In my example code it's attached to the left.

Now I changed the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right` in my example code, but nothing happened in the XAML design window. When I start the example the adorner is actually attached to the right and after that the design window shows the adorner attached to the right. When changing back to `Left` nothing happens in the design window until I update the design window in any way.

I looked in the code of this `AdornedControl` from the link and figured that I need to detect, whether `HorizontalAlignment` changed, and if it does, I need to "redraw" the adorner's content.

And finally here's my question. How do I detect, whether `HorizontalAlignment` changed? I couldn't find a `HorizontalAlignmentChanged` event in `FrameworkElement`. Is there some other way to detect this change?

Comment: WPF uses dependency properties, which have their own "property-changed" paradigm, different from the `XXXChanged` convention found in WinForms. Your question needs a good [mcve] if you want more specific advice than that.

Comment: There are a few XXXChanged events for dependency properties on a `FrameWorkElement` (I counted 14, for instance `SizeChanged`), and does it really need a XAML example of how to use `HorizontalAlignment` to explain, what event one needs to add a handler to to be able to react on changes in the value of a dependeny property called `HorizontalAlignment`?

The example would look like this: `<Button Content="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Instead of using "AddHandler" and "RemoveHandler" for the non-existing event one can use "AddValueChanged" and "RemoveValueChanged" in the code behind or the view model code.

To add a "ValueChanged" event handler to a dependency property one can use:

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(<FrameWorkElement>)(<Name_Of_Dep_Property>).AddValueChanged(<FrameWorkElement>, <Pointer_To_Event_Handler_Code>)
```

For instance:

```
TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Me.TestButton)("HorizontalAlignment").AddValueChanged(Me.TestButton, AddressOf Alignment_ValueChanged)

Private Sub Alignment_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub
```

To remove the event handler again just use "RemoveValueChanged" instead of "AddValueChanged".

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is not a good idea in general. Try this (works with any dependency property):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor
        .FromProperty(TextBlock.TextProperty, typeof(TextBlock));
    if (dpd != null)
    {
        dpd.AddValueChanged(txtBlock, OnTextChanged);
    }
}

private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The value of the Text property of the TextBlock was changed!");
}
```

Source: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/03/31/handling-changes-to-dependency-properties/